# Why the adjectives are always placed after the pronoun "something"?

Tags: grammar

Why are the adjectives always placed after the pronoun "something"? For example: "Something black", "Something else", "Something funny" ... 
Also are there any other pronouns like this one?

Comment: Anything, everything, nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any answer beside "because that is the way English is", but every *some*- word works that way (*somewhere bad, someone tall*) and so do quantifiers (*There are two red and three black and a few green*)

Comment: Afaik the archaic or dialect terms "aught" and "naught" work the same way.  "Else" was originally a genitive in Old English, and OE sometimes had other genitives in the same position, e.g. áwuht gódes (= aught of good = anything good) (see "else" in the OED).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the compounds with *some/any/every/no*+*thing/one/body* work this way. These are historically noun phrases, with *thing/one/body* acting as the nominal and *some/any/every/no* acting as the quantifier-determiner. If the compound is treated as two words, an adjectival would naturally be placed between the determiner and the nominal:

> some black thing
>   any honest body ... *note, by the way, that* body *in this generic sense of "person" survives today almost exclusively in dialect*

But when you re-analyze *some*+*thing* as a single word you lock the adjective out of that position, so it has to be placed after the nominal:

> something black
>   anybody honest

Comment: -where and -place compounds work this way too.

Comment: @rjpond Hmm ... I think postpositive adjectives with those are motivated by analogy. The *-where* compounds aren't reversible any more: *where* is no longer used as a nominal, as Shakespeare did with *some other where*. And it seems to me that closing up *place* with its quantifier is very rare: it's usually written as two words, and the adjective can fall either before or after the nominal.

Comment: Specifically regarding something, there are such phrases as e.g. _sixty something, John something_ or _a little something_. Following the same paradigm, maybe _grey-bluish something_ makes sense?

Comment: @MvLog That's a very good point. I'd argue that in those cases we're dealing with a slightly different use of *something* to make the indefiniteness focal rather than incidental: not merely an omission of definiteness (I may know what it is and just not be defining it) but a 'positive absence' of definiteness (I definitely don't know what it is).

Comment: @MvLog In "Would you care for a little something"?, "something" is a noun formed by conversion from the compound determinative.

Comment: @BillJ An elegant take on it. I don't think we can remind learners too often that English-as-she-is-actually-used recategorizes words very freely.

Comment: @StoneyB:  Expletives can squeeze between. *Once again, my car keys are nowhere to be found. -- Well, they've gotta be some-f_cking-where!*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Fersher. But is that an adjective modifying *where* or a discourse-marking infix? It would also work preceding *some*.

Answer (score 4):

Traditional grammar analyses "something" as a pronoun, but a more modern approach takes it as a compound determinative.

There is a constraint on the position of certain modifiers called 'restrictors' that can be used to modify such compounds. The restrictors (adjectives or certain nominals) cannot occur in pre-head position because of the fused nature of the construction and are forced into post-head position, with only "else" allowed between them and the head:

> “nothing (else) significant”
>
> "everything gold"
>
> "somewhere beautiful”
>
> "nowhere special"
>
> "somebody rich"